# How to get json banner by selecting key:value pair

Tags: json, jq

I have a json banner file as "extract_3month_fromshodan.json" which have key-value for multiple tag i.e. ip_str=XXX.XX.XXX.XX, port=80, timestamp="2018-08-11T04:56:17.312039", data= "210!connection successful" etc. In this way the file has banner for almost 400 IP's.

Sample of source/json banner (extract_3month_fromshodan.json)  file:

```
{
  "asn": "AS17676",
  "hash": -619087650,
  "ip": 2120548325,
  "isp": "Softbank BB",
  "transport": "udp",
  "data": "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nCache-Control: max-age=120\r\nST:  upnp:rootdevice\r\nUSN: uuid:12342409-1234-1234-5678-ee1234cc5678::upnp:rootdevice\r\nEXT:\r\nServer: miniupnpd/1.0 UPnP/1.0\r\nLocation: http://192.168.2.1:52869/picsdesc.xml\r\n\r\n",
  "port": 1900,
  "hostnames": [
  "softbank126100255229.bbtec.net"
 ],
  "location": {
  "city": "Toyota",
  "region_code": "01",
  "area_code": null,
  "longitude": 137.14999999999998,
  "country_code3": "JPN",
  "latitude": 35.08330000000001,
  "postal_code": "457-0844",
  "dma_code": null,
  "country_code": "JP",
  "country_name": "Japan"
 },
  "timestamp": **"2018-09-12T15:42:34.012436",**
  "domains": [
  "bbtec.net"
 ],
  "org": "XXXXXX BB",
  "os": null,
  "_shodan": {
  "crawler": "d264629436af1b777b3b513ca6ed1404d7395d80",
  "options": {},
  "module": "upnp",
  "id": null
 },
  "opts": {},
  "ip_str": **"126.100.255.229"**
}

{
 "asn": "AS17676",
 "hash": 1371060454,
 "ip": 2120509894,
 "isp": "Softbank BB",
 "transport": "udp",
 "data": "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nCache-Control: max-age=1800\r\nST: upnp:rootdevice\r\nUSN: uuid:63041253-1019-2006-1228-00018efed688::upnp:rootdevice\r\nEXT:\r\nServer: OS 1.0 UPnP/1.0 Realtek/V1.3\r\nLocation: http://192.168.2.1:52881/simplecfg.xml\r\n\r\n",
 "port": 1900,
 "hostnames": [
 "softbank126100105198.bbtec.net"
],
 "location": {
 "city": "Yamashitacho",
 "region_code": "18",
 "area_code": null,
 "longitude": 130.55,
 "country_code3": "JPN",
 "latitude": 31.58330000000001,
 "postal_code": "892-0816",
 "dma_code": null,
 "country_code": "JP",
 "country_name": "Japan"
},
 "timestamp": **"2018-08-11T04:56:17.312039"**,
 "domains": [
 "bbtec.net"
],
 "org": "Softbank BB",
 "os": null,
 "_shodan": {
 "crawler": "6ff540e4d43ec69d8de2a7b60e1de2d9ddb406dc",
 "options": {},
 "module": "upnp",
 "id": null
 },
 "opts": {},
 "ip_str": **"126.100.105.198"**
}
```

Now I want to get another new json banner from the source json file above (extract_3month_fromshodan.json) by filtering  the parameter i.e. ip_str="126.100.105.198" and timestamp="2018-08-11T04:56:17.312039". 
The iterative values for each ip_str and timestamp are to come from separate .csv and/or .txt file. And the output (filtered banner) is needed to save as json format.

What I have done so far :

```
jq '. | select (.timestamp="2018-08-11T04:56:17.312039") | select(.ip_str==""12X.10X.XXX.X9X")' extract_3month_fromshodan.json > all.json
```

In this way I need to get for almost 290 times of ip_str,timestamp values which are kept in a csv and or .txt file. What I have done is for single ip_str and timestamp. But I could not able to run the above command as a loop.

Expected Output :

I should get extracted/filtered json banner including all relevant fields w.r.t 290 IPs and timestamp (kept in csv or txt file) from the main json banner (containing more than 500 IPs). The extraction should be done automatically i.e. like a loop command by one/group of code. the values (timestamp and ip_str) for loop will come from .csv or .txt file.

For the mini use case here (filtering 1 out of two ), In input,I have input banner for two IPs i.e. 126.100.255.229 and 126.100.105.198. Now after running loop command I should get banner for ip_str=126.100.105.198 having timestamp = 2018-08-11T04:56:17.312039 as below. In real case I will have banner for more than 500 IPs and timestamp in one json file from I which I have to filtered for 290 IPs and timestamp.

Output :

```
{
  "asn": "AS17676",
  "hash": 1371060454,
  "ip": 2120509894,
  "isp": "Softbank BB",
  "transport": "udp",
  "data": "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nCache-Control: max-age=1800\r\nST: upnp:rootdevice\r\nUSN: uuid:63041253-1019-2006-1228-00018efed688::upnp:rootdevice\r\nEXT:\r\nServer: OS 1.0 UPnP/1.0 Realtek/V1.3\r\nLocation:   http://192.168.2.1:52881/simplecfg.xml\r\n\r\n",
  "port": 1900,
  "hostnames": [
  "softbank126100105198.bbtec.net"
],
  "location": {
  "city": "Yamashitacho",
  "region_code": "18",
  "area_code": null,
  "longitude": 130.55,
  "country_code3": "JPN",
  "latitude": 31.58330000000001,
  "postal_code": "892-0816",
  "dma_code": null,
  "country_code": "JP",
  "country_name": "Japan"
},
  "timestamp": "2018-08-11T04:56:17.312039",
  "domains": [
  "bbtec.net"
],
  "org": "Softbank BB",
  "os": null,
  "_shodan": {
  "crawler": "6ff540e4d43ec69d8de2a7b60e1de2d9ddb406dc",
  "options": {},
  "module": "upnp",
  "id": null
 },
  "opts": {},
  "ip_str": **"126.100.105.198"**
}
```

Actual Result:

I am getting the filtered output/json banner based on filter parameter (here in this case ip_str and timestamp) for one single combination by running the above code.
     jq '. | select (.timestamp="2018-08-11T04:56:17.312039") | select(.ip_str=="126.100.105.198")' extract_3month_fromshodan.json > all.json

Actual Problem:

But the problem is I have to run the above code manually for 290 times for  IP's which is trouble some. So, how can I use this command so that it could run for other 290 times repetitively automatically.

Comment: Your question would be easier to understand and to answer if you followed the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: hi peak. thank you for your suggestions. I have modified the text to make it more clear. To reproduce the case I must upload the original file here but I am not sure whether it is good to do!

Comment: Please read the [mcve] guidelines carefully. The example should be MINIMAL but should include both the input and the expected output. It should (in cases such as this) be easily VERIFIABLE - please do not include images of data. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Infact to reproduce a verifiable case I need to add one json file here but didn't find any option to that. Hence I edited the content again to make it more understandable.

Comment: Getting closer, but the input example should be complete (and minimal). Also, you have not specified how the values in each query are to be specified.  You mention a loop, without saying where the values in each iteration are to come from.   And where should the results of each query go?

Comment: Thanks for continuous feedback. I have again made the changes what you have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the piece of the puzzle you're missing is the ability to pass values into jq using command-line options such as `--arg`.  The following should therefore get you over the hump:

```
while read -r ts ip
do
  jq --arg ts "$ts" --arg ip "$ip" '
    select(.timestamp==$ts and .ip_str==$ip)
  ' extract_3month_fromshodan.json
done < <(cat<<EOF     
2018-08-11T04:56:17.312039 126.100.105.198
EOF
)
```

### inputfile.txt

So if `inputfile.txt` contains the ts-ip pairs as above, you could write:

```
while read -r ts ip
do
  jq --arg ts "$ts" --arg ip "$ip" '
    select(.timestamp==$ts and .ip_str==$ip)
  ' extract_3month_fromshodan.json
done < inputfile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. How did you consider the Input file i..e format and have you considered a single or multiple input file for time and IP?

Comment: I took inputfile.txt   :                                                                                                                                          2018-08-11T04:56:17.312039 126.100.105.198
2018-09-12T15:42:34.012436 126.100.255.229                                                        Modified the last part of your code as                                                     (cat<<EOF     
inputfile.txt
EOF
)                                                                                                                                     But output data is not filtered.

Comment: I made the mistake of copying your "select" criteria.  The "=" should have been "==". I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: But now getting no output by the updated command. Further, where should I mention the inputfile.txt from where the loop will take the values?

Comment: I am facing a pecuiliar problem. While executing the updated code, it was ran. But there were no output was given. Just executing without any output.

Comment: Try copy-and-paste. For the JSON, use your sample except of  course for the occurrences of  “**”.

Comment: I copied and paste the above code. Keeping the sample file (inputfile.txt) having the same format as you described.  As a test case I kept only 3 rows i.e.        2018-08-11T04:56:17.312039 126.100.105.198
2018-09-12T15:42:34.012436 126.100.255.229
2018-08-15T03:37:40.381560 126.107.19.222                                                         But still got not output though the code was executed. But if I changed some part of the  code a bit i.e. select(.timestamp=$ts and .ip_str==$ip) instead of select(.timestamp==$ts and .ip_str==$ip) then it gives output but without filtering .

Comment: But the previous command is working fine and giving the output properly.   Copying the code and pasting giving the result properly.                                                     while read -r ts ip
do
  jq --arg ts "$ts" --arg ip "$ip" '
    select(.timestamp==$ts and .ip_str==$ip)
  ' extract_3month_fromshodan.json
done < <(cat<<EOF     
2018-08-11T04:56:17.312039 126.100.105.198
EOF
)

Comment: Make sure you have "ip" and "$ip" used consistently. 
 Maybe you should start from scratch.  Or ask someone to check your code and data.  You might also like to learn how to debug things yourself, e.g. using the jq `debug` filter.

Comment: Sure I will do it accordingly. Thank you for your continuous help.

Comment: I tried to identify the root cause. I think the problem was in file name. I changed the file name from "inputdata.txt" or "inputfile.txt" to "uniqip_3m_shodan.txt" and then it is working. But the looping is not occurring accurately i.e. for a set of datas/lines, the code is reading the last line only. But If I follow a consecutive pattern i.e. add one line and run, adding another line and run  then it can give output for all the lines .